# tufte-latex: \newthought after \section

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, typography, tufte

Using `\newthought` after a new section title inserts an unusual vertical space as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,cleveref}


\begin{document}

\section{Monday}
\kant[1]

\section{Tuesday}
\newthought{Let us suppose} that the noumena have nothing to do with necessity,
since knowledge of the Categories is a posteriori. 
\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Is there an (preferably automatic) way to correct this?
2. Should `\newthought` be avoided after a section title maybe due to typographic reasons? If the answer is yes I would appreciate an explanation *why*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of `\tuftebreak` can be improved:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\tuftebreak{%
  \if@nobreak\else
    \par
    \ifdim\lastskip<\tufteskipamount
      \removelastskip \penalty -100
      \tufteskip
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Monday}
\kant[1]

\section{Tuesday}
\newthought{Let us suppose} that the noumena have nothing to do with necessity,
since knowledge of the Categories is a posteriori.
\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about \removelastskip.